# discord.io - Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'avatar')

Tags: node.js, server, discord, hosting

I've got a discord bot I made using the discord.io npm package.

The bot runs fine from my laptop, and I had been running it on Heroku without any startup problems.

I'm currently trying to switch from Heroku to Sparked Hosting (with their basic plan)
I loaded in all my files via FTP, and I think I correctly listed out all my packages that need installing.

When I try to start the server, I get this error message, and then it crashes.[image]

The error seems to happen entirely within the package files, and, again, it didn't happen on my computer or on Heroku.  I don't know if I missed something in setup, or if there's something unique to Sparked Host creating the problem.

I tried uploading all my files and listing dependencies. It seems like it's running my program to the point of attempting to login to Discord before it crashes.  I'm currently feeding it Discord's auth token via a .env file and the dotenv node package (I can't seem to figure out how to set environment variables with Sparked Host's server).  I know it's no secure, but it seems to be working at least.

I'm not really sure what to try from this point.

Answer (score 0):

I built my first discord bot.  It runs fine locally on my server. I can upload it to daki.cc and it runs fine there too.

As soon as I add the bot to my game's discord server I get this same error (both locally running node and on daki.cc.

I don't understand why adding it to another server causes this error.

It's node 18.12.1 locally, 18.12.0 on daki, but I doubt that's a problem.

I'm not trying to set an avatar.  The logo I put on the bot page is showing on the game server.

If I kick the bot from the game discord server it magically works again.

see also [Cannot set property 'avatar' of undefined at Member.set [as avatar] - Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67670300/cannot-set-property-avatar-of-undefined-at-member-set-as-avatar-discord-bo) but it didn't help me because editing the discord.io library is a hairy proposition on the hosted server.

Edit: I gave up on discord.io and rewrote the whole thing using discord.js 14.  Now it works.  Yes, there are a number of differences (read breakage).  Yes, differences between discord.js 13 and 14 made working with documentation and references difficult.